# Too many values to unpack about signal.butter

Tags: python-3.x, filter, signals

```
def bandPassFilter(data, samplerate):
    wn1 = 2 * 0.9 / samplerate  # origin 0.667 
    wn2 = 2 * 2.5 / samplerate
    b, a = signal.butter(N=8, Wn=[wn1, wn2], btype='bandpass')  # Too many values to unpack 
    data = signal.filtfilt(b, a, data)
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
btype='bandpass'
```

With:

```
btype='band'
```